# Breadcrumbs Navigation Requirement Changed

Tags: 2007, development, master-page, navigation, breadcrumb

**Scenario**

I have 20's of site in a single site collection we can say "portal A", Now I have list of site collections, let me explain it using a tree

[image: Example of my Portal]

Now we are creating breadcrumb navigation using a user control, which is placed in our master page and gets populated using this custom user control. I am not sure if we get values from SiteMap or Database maybe at few places we take it from database, but then we created another master page with another user control for that.

**Problem**

I have a give a link to "1.2.1.1.1" on  "1.1.2.2.1" so that when a user click on the link he will be navigated to the site "1.1.2.2.1", and the breadcrumb changes from this

1 > 1.1 > 1.1.2 > 1.1.2.2.1

to this

1 > 1.2 > 1.2.1 > 1.2.1.1 > 1.2.1.1.1

which makes user confuse if they wanna go back from where they came from.Now problem is that these site's name are quiet random and they keep changing, so I can't think of any possible way at the moment using which, I can solve this problem.

I mean I have two ways to go to a site, but I want two breadcrumbs Navigations for it

or **In short   I want a BreadCrumb for that will show the path, I came from not the path Its getting from SiteMap or Database.**

Thanks Alot for your time, btw I am using SharePoint 2007

cHeers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same kind of requirement . . Create a custom control and add it to all the master pages of your 20 sites.
For each site maintain a list ,which stores the name and url of the link.
there is a property page.UrlRefferer which will give you where you came from.you can use this property